# Image carousel with circular scroll view

Tags: java, android

Actually i want to implement the following carousel.The idea is that as long as you spin the circular bar it displays images categorized with different colors.I don't know where to start from .I thought about mixing a circular scroll view with the carousel but i am not sure if it's right. Could you please share ideas or tutorials with me ? i will be grateful to that.

[image]

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to let you know I am working on creating the view displayed in the screenshot. Here is what mine's looking so far: https://picload.org/image/rplggppa/working.png I hope I can finish it soon. I will post an answer with more info and source soon.

Comment: Same here , iam working on it but , i will be waiting to see yours too , Thanks alot for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to create a kind of circular seekbar with a custom style that will be modified on progress changed. You will be able the section you want by checking the progress of the seekbar.

A github project exist to make a circular seekbar :
https://github.com/RaghavSood/AndroidCircularSeekBar